# Menu items order on mobile version (float problems)

Tags: html, css, responsive

When my menu go to hamburger menu items get `display:block` value.
But my items don't get right order because of `float:right` property on last 3 items.

I am stuck with ideas, I can make 2 menus but I think that is not right way.

[codepen preview here](http://codepen.io/AttilaBre/pen/LLPqqx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a different order without creating two menus take a look at using flexbox and the order property: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp

In mobile view something along the lines of:

```
header ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header ul li:nth-child(5) {
    order: 7;
}

header ul li:nth-child(6) {
    order: 6;
}
```

Comment: Thx for helping I rare use flex because of Internet explorer incompatibility.

But in this project I can use it!

Answer (score 0):

As being said by itodd, you can use Flexbox `order` property. Or you can simply wrap the items on right in some container and `float: right` that. So when you will be on mobile, you will have the same order of items.

**EDIT:**

Althrough I would go for not absolute positionated layout, e.g. use Flexbox with 3 wrappers, 1st and 3rd for items and 2nd for logo. Then you can simply use `align-items: flex-end` (or `justify-content: flex-end;`; I never know) to have a nice positionated menu.

Comment: This will work, however the HTML will not be valid as only li are allowed as children of ul

Comment: Sure. However usage of `ul` & `li` is not required in this case. I edited my answer's idea.

Comment: Of course any elements can be used but for menus it is a common accessibility practice to build a list of links with `ul`

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I believe it's better to use divs w/o absolute position than absolute positionated `ul`s. You can't always go for best practise – you should go for easy self-sustaining solutions, which absolute position is not.